# Convert a Decimal column in pandas into a float column

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following dataframe:

```py
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'price': [Decimal(1.4334), Decimal(1.4335), Decimal(1.4336), Decimal(1.4337)], 'tpo_count': [1, 2, 3, 1], 'tpo': ['A', 'BC', 'BCD', 'D']})
print(df2.dtypes)

price        object
tpo_count     int64
tpo          object
dtype: object
```

If want ot create an additional column named "price_float" which is the same column as "price" but with floats (to be later draw using matplotlib which does not support Decimal).

I have tried:

```
df2['price_float']=float(df2['price'])
```

but I get:

```
TypeError: cannot convert the series to <class 'float'>
```

Comment: `df2['price_float'] = df2['price_float'].astype(float)`. Did you actually try researching how to change types?

Comment: This is the way to go as @roganjosh said.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just simulating your sample DataFrame:

### Sample DataFarme:

```
>>> df2
    price  tpo  tpo_count
0  1.4334    A          1
1  1.4335   BC          2
2  1.4336  BCD          3
3  1.4337    D          1
>>> print(df2.dtypes)
price        object
tpo          object
tpo_count     int64
dtype: object
```

### Solution..

```
>>> df2['price_float'] = df2['price'].astype(float)
>>> df2
    price  tpo  tpo_count  price_float
0  1.4334    A          1       1.4334
1  1.4335   BC          2       1.4335
2  1.4336  BCD          3       1.4336
3  1.4337    D          1       1.4337
```

now you got new `float` column created..

```
>>> print(df2.dtypes)
price           object
tpo             object
tpo_count        int64
price_float    float64
dtype: object
```

Comment: Will the numbers in `decimal.Decimal` be ALWAYS retained during conversion to float? i.e. any possible changes of values, like `round up` or `round down`?

Comment: @Gathide Decimal and float are different beasts, so yes the numbers may change very slightly, which is the whole reason for Decimal type existing in the first place. Good summary: https://docs.python.org/3/library/decimal.html

Answer (score 1):

You can use astype function:

```
 df.astype({'col1': 'int32'}).dtypes
```